# zfs arc very small while a lot of reading going on

Tags: linux, debian, zfs

Debian server with nginx proxy_cache on zfs ssd with 50Gb of files. Arc max_arc_size set to 4Gb, but it is allways about 200Mb. There are about 15Mb/s reads (~2000 iops).

Here are the arc stats:

```
6 1 0x01 91 4368 4519739210 20260794068709869
name                            type data
hits                            4    1091659308
misses                          4    2527747210
demand_data_hits                4    199239091
demand_data_misses              4    879731305
demand_metadata_hits            4    878147163
demand_metadata_misses          4    1620108834
prefetch_data_hits              4    3576788
prefetch_data_misses            4    26135774
prefetch_metadata_hits          4    10696266
prefetch_metadata_misses        4    1771297
mru_hits                        4    748623935
mru_ghost_hits                  4    4693446
mfu_hits                        4    329085083
mfu_ghost_hits                  4    572404
deleted                         4    3416733423
mutex_miss                      4    2921118
evict_skip                      4    1998987007908
evict_not_enough                4    65487161254
evict_l2_cached                 4    8503750861312
evict_l2_eligible               4    53782247538176
evict_l2_ineligible             4    1007328996352
evict_l2_skip                   4    123543938
hash_elements                   4    547710
hash_elements_max               4    12455750
hash_collisions                 4    4764403886
hash_chains                     4    33097
hash_chain_max                  4    17
p                               4    2171871232
c                               4    4294967296
c_min                           4    1073741824
c_max                           4    4294967296
size                            4    197336056
hdr_size                        4    2416376
data_size                       4    19205120
metadata_size                   4    88721920
other_size                      4    30579920
anon_size                       4    26062848
anon_evictable_data             4    0
anon_evictable_metadata         4    0
mru_size                        4    80666112
mru_evictable_data              4    1671168
mru_evictable_metadata          4    4380160
mru_ghost_size                  4    0
mru_ghost_evictable_data        4    0
mru_ghost_evictable_metadata    4    0
mfu_size                        4    1198080
mfu_evictable_data              4    0
mfu_evictable_metadata          4    540672
mfu_ghost_size                  4    0
mfu_ghost_evictable_data        4    0
mfu_ghost_evictable_metadata    4    0
l2_hits                         4    375974103
l2_misses                       4    2145995954
l2_feeds                        4    20211060
l2_rw_clash                     4    463
l2_read_bytes                   4    6363894670336
l2_write_bytes                  4    4125367876608
l2_writes_sent                  4    15985006
l2_writes_done                  4    15985006
l2_writes_error                 4    0
l2_writes_lock_retry            4    14130
l2_evict_lock_retry             4    268
l2_evict_reading                4    1
l2_evict_l1cached               4    159
l2_free_on_write                4    1407463
l2_cdata_free_on_write          4    17
l2_abort_lowmem                 4    36
l2_cksum_bad                    4    0
l2_io_error                     4    0
l2_size                         4    14377400320
l2_asize                        4    14376536576
l2_hdr_size                     4    56412720
l2_compress_successes           4    1844601
l2_compress_zeros               4    0
l2_compress_failures            4    145
memory_throttle_count           4    0
duplicate_buffers               4    0
duplicate_buffers_size          4    0
duplicate_reads                 4    0
memory_direct_count             4    1
memory_indirect_count           4    9
arc_no_grow                     4    0
arc_tempreserve                 4    0
arc_loaned_bytes                4    0
arc_prune                       4    283684792692
arc_meta_used                   4    178130936
arc_meta_limit                  4    107374182
arc_meta_max                    4    1415965680
arc_meta_min                    4    16777216
arc_need_free                   4    0
arc_sys_free                    4    131072
```

Here are the zfs params:

```
l2arc_feed_again                 1
l2arc_feed_min_ms                200
l2arc_feed_secs                  1
l2arc_headroom           8
l2arc_headroom_boost             200
l2arc_nocompress                 1
l2arc_noprefetch                 0
l2arc_norw               0
l2arc_write_boost                8388608
l2arc_write_max                  83886080
metaslab_aliquot                 524288
metaslab_bias_enabled            1
metaslab_debug_load              0
metaslab_debug_unload            0
metaslab_fragmentation_factor_enabled            1
metaslab_lba_weighting_enabled           1
metaslab_preload_enabled                 1
metaslabs_per_vdev               200
spa_asize_inflation              24
spa_config_path                  /etc/zfs/zpool.cache
spa_load_verify_data             1
spa_load_verify_maxinflight              10000
spa_load_verify_metadata                 1
spa_slop_shift           5
zfetch_array_rd_sz               1048576
zfetch_block_cap                 256
zfetch_max_streams               8
zfetch_min_sec_reap              2
zfs_admin_snapshot               0
zfs_arc_average_blocksize                8192
zfs_arc_grow_retry               1
zfs_arc_lotsfree_percent                 10
zfs_arc_max              4294967296
zfs_arc_meta_adjust_restarts             4096
zfs_arc_meta_limit               0
zfs_arc_meta_min                 0
zfs_arc_meta_prune               10000
zfs_arc_meta_strategy            1
zfs_arc_min              100
zfs_arc_min_prefetch_lifespan            0
zfs_arc_num_sublists_per_state           8
zfs_arc_p_aggressive_disable             1
zfs_arc_p_dampener_disable               1
zfs_arc_p_min_shift              4
zfs_arc_shrink_shift             5
zfs_arc_sys_free                 131072
zfs_autoimport_disable           1
zfs_dbgmsg_enable                0
zfs_dbgmsg_maxsize               4194304
zfs_dbuf_state_index             0
zfs_deadman_enabled              1
zfs_deadman_synctime_ms                  1000000
zfs_dedup_prefetch               0
zfs_delay_min_dirty_percent              60
zfs_delay_scale                  500000
zfs_dirty_data_max               3370398924
zfs_dirty_data_max_max           8425997312
zfs_dirty_data_max_max_percent           25
zfs_dirty_data_max_percent               10
zfs_dirty_data_sync              67108864
zfs_disable_dup_eviction                 0
zfs_expire_snapshot              300
zfs_flags                0
zfs_free_leak_on_eio             0
zfs_free_max_blocks              100000
zfs_free_min_time_ms             1000
zfs_immediate_write_sz           327680
zfs_max_recordsize               1048576
zfs_mdcomp_disable               0
zfs_metaslab_fragmentation_threshold             70
zfs_mg_fragmentation_threshold           85
zfs_mg_noalloc_threshold                 0
zfs_nocacheflush                 1
zfs_nopwrite_enabled             1
zfs_no_scrub_io                  0
zfs_no_scrub_prefetch            0
zfs_pd_bytes_max                 52428800
zfs_prefetch_disable             0
zfs_read_chunk_size              16384
zfs_read_history                 0
zfs_read_history_hits            0
zfs_recover              0
zfs_resilver_delay               2
zfs_resilver_min_time_ms                 3000
zfs_scan_idle            50
zfs_scan_min_time_ms             1000
zfs_scrub_delay                  4
zfs_send_corrupt_data            0
zfs_sync_pass_deferred_free              2
zfs_sync_pass_dont_compress              5
zfs_sync_pass_rewrite            2
zfs_top_maxinflight              32
zfs_txg_history                  0
zfs_txg_timeout                  5
zfs_vdev_aggregation_limit               131072
zfs_vdev_async_read_max_active           3
zfs_vdev_async_read_min_active           1
zfs_vdev_async_write_active_max_dirty_percent            60
zfs_vdev_async_write_active_min_dirty_percent            30
zfs_vdev_async_write_max_active                  10
zfs_vdev_async_write_min_active                  1
zfs_vdev_cache_bshift            18
zfs_vdev_cache_max               16384
zfs_vdev_cache_size              0
zfs_vdev_max_active              1000
zfs_vdev_mirror_switch_us                10000
zfs_vdev_read_gap_limit                  32768
zfs_vdev_scheduler               noop
zfs_vdev_scrub_max_active                2
zfs_vdev_scrub_min_active                1
zfs_vdev_sync_read_max_active            10
zfs_vdev_sync_read_min_active            10
zfs_vdev_sync_write_max_active           10
zfs_vdev_sync_write_min_active           10
zfs_vdev_write_gap_limit                 4096
zfs_zevent_cols                  80
zfs_zevent_console               0
zfs_zevent_len_max               128
zil_replay_disable               0
zil_slog_limit           1048576
zio_delay_max            30000
zio_requeue_io_start_cut_in_line                 1
zvol_inhibit_dev                 0
zvol_major               230
zvol_max_discard_blocks                  16384
zvol_prefetch_bytes              131072
```

Can not figure out what is wrong.

P.S.: arc_reclaim is constantly in the top of CPU eaters.

Comment: *Can not figure out what is wrong.*  Other than the ARC utilization being smaller than you expect, what's wrong?

Comment: Yes. Arc is almost empty with 20Mb/s read load.

Comment: Here is arcstat: `arcstat.py -f l2asize,l2bytes,l2read,l2hit%,read,mread,dread,mru,mfu,mh%,dh%,hit%,arcsz,c 60
l2asize  l2bytes  l2read  l2hit%  read  mread  dread   mru   mfu  mh%  dh%  hit%  arcsz     c  
    16G        0       0       0     0     0      0     0     0    0    0     0   215M  4.0G  
    16G     114K    2.2K       0  4.2K  2.5K   2.6K   849   100   57   36    47   200M  4.0G  
`

Comment: That's just more evidence that ARC utilization doesn't meet your expectations.  Why do you expect ARC utilization to be higher?  What if your application(s) just keep reading the same data over and over?

Comment: This is a cache of images in nginx with this config: proxy_cache_path  /nginx/cachePics  levels=1:1    keys_zone=STATIC6:2000m inactive=1d  max_size=100g use_temp_path=off; So there are only files which was accessed during last 24 hours; And they are about 52Gb now. So they all have bean read at least once for the last 24 hours.

Comment: How much free ram do you have in the server ?. as arc is using ram so if there is not enough ram it wont expand